# My app with utf8 works fine in eclipse but it doesn't in terminal

Tags: java, macos, utf-8

I have an app developed with `Java`. When I test it in `Eclipse`, it works perfectly. Every characters is perfect, but when I compile and export the jar and test it with the OS X terminal, the strange characters *(I'm spanish)* are wrong. They are a "?".

I think I use `UTF-8` everywhere, so I dont know what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you are *not* using UTF-8 everywhere, but have some code that defaults to the platform encoding (which in turn can be set by environment variables and is likely different between Eclipse, where it is set to match the workspace file encoding and your shell).

Make sure you explicitly have "UTF-8" as the charset in all character conversions (such as opening readers) in your code.

For example, don't use

```
Reader r = new FileReader("a.txt");
```

use

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("a.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

If that is not possible, the short-term solution would be to set the appropriate environment variables or system properties (I think `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`).

Comment: When I export the project, the encoding is utf-8. In my terminal too. I don't know why if I run the app with the Eclipse, it runs well but in the terminal, with the jar, it doesn't

Comment: Yes, if I pipe the result to a file, in the file everything is perfect

Comment: Then it seems to be problem with the terminal display itself. Or maybe just the font?

Comment: In the terminal, I have all of the options with utf8...I'll try another font

Answer (score 1):

Check your locale using `locale` command on the terminal. The strings printed should contain `.UTF-8`, `.utf8` or a similar suffix. If they don't, you're using a non-UTF-8 locale and the output of your app is not displayed properly. I'm not sure which locales will be available, but you can try running `export LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8` before you run the app, and check if that helps.

Comment: I did it and this is the result:

LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="es_ES.UTF-8"

Comment: Also try `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.